# Can I solve it with Shapeless?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Suppose I have a few functions:

```
val f1: Int => String
val f2: (Int, Int) => String
val f3: (Int, Int, Int) => String

def fromList1(f: Int => String): List[Int] => Option[String] = 
  _ match {case x::_ => Some(f(x)); case _ => None}

def fromList2(f: (Int, Int) => String): List[Int] => Option[String] = 
  _ match {case x::y::_ => Some(f(x, y)); case _ => None}
```

Now I would like to write one generic `fromList` to work as follows:

```
val g1: List[Int] => String = fromList(f1) // as fromList1(f1)
val g2: List[Int] => String = fromList(f2) // as fromList2(f2)
```

Can I do that with `shapeless` ?

Comment: not for lists, but the idea is same: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#facilities-for-abstracting-over-arity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may help:

```
import shapeless._
import syntax.std.traversable._
import shapeless.ops.traversable._
import syntax.std.function._
import ops.function._

def fromList[F, L <: HList, R](f: F)
 (implicit fp: FnToProduct.Aux[F, L => R], tr: FromTraversable[L]) = 
   (p: List[Int]) => p.toHList[L] map f.toProduct
```

`f.toProduct` transforms regular function to function that takes `HList` as parameter - it requires `FnToProduct` implicit and actually just call it. `FnToProduct.Aux` is constructor (generated by macro) that creates `FnToProduct` from dunction `F`, hlist type `HList` and result type `R`. All of them are inferred from `f` parameter you passed.

Last one, `toHList` creates `Some(HList)` from regular `List` if it's possible, otherwise - `None`. It uses `FromTraversable[L]` implicit to do that, where `L` is already inferred from `f`. Shapeless2 is smart enough to recognize `HList` from `Tuple` (as there probably is implicit conversion).

Example:

```
scala> val f1: Int => String = _ => "a"
f1: Int => String = <function1>

scala> val f2: (Int, Int) => String = (_, _) => "a"
f2: (Int, Int) => String = <function2>

scala> val g1 = fromList(f1)
g1: List[Int] => Option[String] = <function1>

scala> g1(List(1))
res6: Option[String] = Some(a)

scala> val g2 = fromList(f2)
g2: List[Int] => Option[String] = <function1>

scala> g2(List(1, 2))
res7: Option[String] = Some(a)

scala> g2(List(1))
res8: Option[String] = None
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.traversable._
import syntax.std.traversable._
import ops.function._

def fromList[F, I <: HList, O](f: F)(implicit
  ftp: FnToProduct.Aux[F, I => O],
  ft: shapeless.ops.traversable.FromTraversable[I]): List[Int] => Option[O] =
    { x: List[Int] => x.toHList[I].map(ftp(f)) }
```

**Explanation**

We're using `FnToProduct` to transform any `FunctionN` to a `Function1` that takes an `HList` as only argument.

So,

```
Int => String         ----> Int :: HNil => String
(Int, Int) => String  ----> Int :: Int :: HNil => String
...
```

Now that we abstracted over the arity of the input parameters for the function, we can simply convert the `List[Int]` to an `HList` that suits the transformed function's input.
In order to perform this conversion we need to a `FromTraversable[I]` in scope.

If everything succeeds we return and `Option[O]` where `O` is the return type of the function.
If the input `List` has the wrong shape, we simply fail returning `None`.

**Usage**

```
@ val f1: Int => String = _.toString
f1: Int => String = <function1>

@ val f2: (Int, Int) => String = (_, _).toString
f2: (Int, Int) => String = <function2>

@ val fromList1 = fromList(f1)
fromList1: List[Int] => Option[String] = <function1>

@ val fromList2 = fromList(f2)
fromList2: List[Int] => Option[String] = <function1>

@ fromList1(List(1))
res22: Option[String] = Some(1)

@ fromList2(List(1, 2))
res23: Option[String] = Some((1,2))

@ fromList1(List())
res24: Option[String] = None
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.